# Algebraic Elements and Fields of Quotients

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

The algebraic elements of $\mathbb{R}$ are those elements which are roots of nonzero polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$. In fact, by multiplying through by denominators, we can even take the polynomials to have coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. My question is, in a sense, about the converse of this situtation in a more general setting.

> Let $\mathbb{L}$ be a field extension of a field $\mathbb{K}$, and let $\mathbb{S}$ be a subring of $\mathbb{K}$ such that every algebraic element of $\mathbb{L}$ is the root of some nonzero polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{S}$. Is $\mathbb{K}$ the field of quotients of $\mathbb{S}$?

Note, as $\mathbb{S}$ is a subring of the field $\mathbb{K}$, it is automatically an integral domain so we can construct the field of quotients of $\mathbb{S}$.

---

As Mariano and pritam's examples show, the answer is no. However, in all of these examples, $\mathbb{K}$ is an algebraic extension of the field of quotients of $\mathbb{S}$. **Is this always the case?**

Comment: Take $\mathbb K=\mathbb L=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ and $\mathbb S=\mathbb Z$.

Comment: If that is too annoying, take $\mathbb K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$, $\mathbb L=\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\pi)$ and $\mathbb S=\mathbb Z$ :-)

Comment: @Mariano: Thank you for your counterexamples. Maybe instead I should ask whether $\mathbb{K}$ must necessarily be an algebraic extension of the field of quotients of $\mathbb{S}$.

Comment: @Michael Precisely what do you mean by an "algebraic element of $\Bbb L$", i.e. algebraic over what field?

Comment: @Bill: I mean algebraic over $\mathbb{K}$.

Comment: @Michael Thanks, just wanted to be  sure, since the downvote on my answer is puzzling, and the only explanation I can imagine is that the voter may have interpreted that differently.

Comment: @Bill: That's OK. I was surprised to see your answer had been downvoted.

Comment: @Michael Reading the other answers, I notice that Gerry's answer is essentially the same as mine, except that he uses proof by contradiction. But I think the proof is clearer directly - as in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning the new question. $K$ is a field containing $S$, so it is an extension of the field $F$ of quotients of $S$. If it's not algebraic over $F$, then it has some element, call it $\pi$, transcendental over $F$. $L$ is an extension of $K$, so it contains $\pi$, and $\pi$ is algebraic over $K$, since it's actually in $K$, but it's not a root of a polynomial with coefficients in $S$, since it's transcendental over $F$. So, for your hypotheses to be met, $K$ must be algebraic over $F$.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

No. Take $\mathbb{L}=\mathbb{C},\mathbb{S}=\mathbb{R},\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Thanks pritam. In your example, as with Mariano's examples, $\mathbb{K}$ is an algebraic extension of the field of quotients of $\mathbb{S}$. Is this necessarily the case? I will edit my post to include this question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes to your new question. Your hypothesis asserts that every element of $L$ algebraic over $K$ is algebraic over the subfield $Q =$ fraction field of $S.$ In particular this is true for all elements of $K$.